# What exercise raises calf insertion?

Tags: calf

I know in general people working calves are looking to bulk them up. I have the opposite problem, my insertion points are too low and makes wearing shorts look stupid.
How do you raise insertion points?

Answer (score 5):

You don't, unless you have surgery to move them. Insertion points, like everything else, are genetically determined.

Comment: that's kinda bogus i know a few people whose parents are not genetically high insertions but they are due to playing sports a huge part of their lifetime. Not trying to shortcut my way in, but are there exercises that would specifically raise these insertion points?

Comment: @user2167582 - No. There is no exercise that will move a muscle's insertion point. None. Period. Full stop. They may have specific *muscle development* due to a lifetime of sports, but the insertion point has not changed. (Barring an injury where it ripped away and reattached). Additionally, the insertion point for the calf is the heel bone (calcaneus) via the achilles tendon, so if you "raise" it, you wouldn't be able to point your foot.

Comment: @user2167582 - I think you may be confusing something - The insertion point for a muscle is not where the muscle fuses into the tendon, but where the tendon anchoring a muscle attaches to the bone. If you are talking about the shape of the muscle and how high on the back of the leg it is, you can't change that, but you can develop the muscle as fully as possible. Some people have high calf muscles, others have lower. It's also genetically determined, but you can develop the calf in different ways.

Comment: ah thanks, I think I know what insertion point means, and I do take you point. Thats a bummer to hear, I really wanted to to get a more athletic leg physique.

Comment: also do you know if any type of exercise would encourage the insertion point to increase / decrease? surely I think given that body adjust itself to match the need of what we do, i think there are at least a few stretching / exercises that would tell the muscle belly to become longer or shorter?

Comment: @user2167582 - Stretching doesn't really lengthen the muscle fibers dramatically. Mostly what it does is train the body not to resist the stretch. Most people when they are unconscious (coma type) can be stretched without harm way beyond what they could when awake. You can develop the muscle as much as possible, but none of that will really change the location of where it ties into the tendon. It may just change the appearance of it.

Comment: i feel like theres gotta be a niche market of people like me who are looking to solve this. I would be curious to see what other's opinions are.

Comment: @user2167582 there is no niche. There is nothing to solve. It is genetic. The only way *might* be surgery. But that would be a year rehab. Per leg. (I am assuming same time frame as a ruptured achilles, that was how long my rehab took).

Answer (score 2):

I think, here genetics is against you. If you are adult - all you can do is to build them, to change proportions. Earlier... not much can be done anyway.

On the other hand, consider your self as lucky person - the longer muscle, the stronger it can be.

Comment: Do you have a reference that a longer muscle is stronger?

Comment: Longer muscle **can be** stronger, not necessarily **is** stronger. More space -> bigger potential muscle can be -> bigger force production. However I can't recall source for that. So I've googled a bit - http://downloads.lww.com/wolterskluwer_vitalstream_com/sample-content/9780781774222_Oatis/samples/Oatis_CH04_045-068.pdf - page 52.